# Cannot get the text of the Linkbutton in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is how I am trying to get the text of the LinkButton:-

```
protected void download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    String name = btn.Text;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select str_file from soham_movies where title='" + name + "'", conn);
    conn.Close();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    string filePath = "";
    filePath = "~/files/" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "movieFiles";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

But I am getting the text as "" (blank).

Here's my aspx part:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BorderStyle="None" AlternatingRowStyle-BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="5" 
    EditRowStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" 
    PagerStyle-BorderStyle="None" RowStyle-BorderStyle="None" ShowHeader="False" 
    GridLines="None" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img id="image" src='<%# Eval("pic") %>' runat="server" style="height:120px; width:150px" />
            </ItemTemplate>                   
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="click_download" runat="server" OnClick="download"><%# Eval("title") %></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The LinkButton's text is visible in the page inside gridView and can be clicked but I face the error of the query not retrieving any result because queried name is  blank

Comment: have you tried using the FindControl method to get the name of the link button.. and from there get the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that due the fact that you are setting the text of the button as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="click_download" runat="server" OnClick="download"><%# Eval("title") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

The `Text` property is not being set correctly. Move the `<%# Eval("title") %>` into the declaration of link button and assign it's value to the `Text` property:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="click_download" runat="server" OnClick="download" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "title") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: But that gives error: "The server tag is not well formed"

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are setting the text property/attribute for the LinkButton. However, I do see where you have "<%# Eval("title") %>" floating in your tag.  Should it say Text="<%# Eval("title") %>".

I really don't understand how it is being viewed if it's not set.  Are you setting it in the Page_Load?  Hopefully these questions help chase down the problem.